# Loop through files in a folder and add date tab

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop

I am trying to go to a set of workbooks in a folder and add a Tab to each named the current date.

My code below opens the first file and adds the Tab correctly, but does not loop to open the remaining files.

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

MyDir = "C:\Users\u558683\Desktop\QA VBA Project\LoopTabs\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
ChDir MyDir


Do While MyFile <> ""

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    TabName = Format(Date, "mmm-yyyy") 'Change the format as per your  requirement

On Error GoTo AddNew
Sheets(TabName).Activate
Exit Sub

AddNew:
 Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
 ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

 ActiveSheet.Previous.Range("A1:AJ4").Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
 ActiveSheet.Previous.Range("AL1:AN500").Copy Destination:=Range("AK1")

 Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a **minute to take the [tour]** to see how SO community works (how to accept answers and use votes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues :

1. you missed the `MyFile = Dir()` that give you the next file name.
2. you used `Exit Sub` which would just get out of the program without continuing treatment.

---

Fixed code :

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()
Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String
Dim Tb As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Set Tb = ThisWorkbook

MyDir = "C:\Users\u558683\Desktop\QA VBA Project\LoopTabs\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")

Do While MyFile <> vbNullString
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(MyDir & MyFile)
    TabName = Format(Date, "mmm-yyyy") 'Change the format as per your  requirement

    On Error Resume Next
    wB.Sheets(TabName).Activate
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        'AddNewSheet
        wB.Sheets.Add , wB.Sheets(wB.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
        ActiveSheet.Previous.Range("A1:AJ4").Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
        ActiveSheet.Previous.Range("AL1:AN500").Copy Destination:=Range("AK1")
        wB.Save
    Else
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    wB.Close False
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I'm learning vba the hard way here!  A couple questions.  First, how to close the files I just opened?  Second, is there another way to differentiate the files to open other than "*.xlsx"?  My concern is the folks add additional files in the folder that do not need the date tab added.

Comment: @Eric : Glad I could help! First of all, as I said in comments : **please take the [tour]** (click it), I see that you have ask a few questions and not accepted any answers, so it's more than time to know how SO works! ;)
Then I've added the part to save the workbook with the new sheet. And to exclude the files, if those you want to add sheets in don't have a common form of naming, it'll be hard to exclude other files... If it has, you can use something like `"*Common_Part_In_Name*.xlsx"`

Comment: Thank you, and I'll definitely take the tour.  I'm going to update my code and try this now.

Comment: @Eric : And after, the tour, come back to accept answers! ;)

Comment: This is works well.  As soon as work allows I'll take the tour.  Thanks.

Comment: @Eric : It'll take less time than posting a comment! ;) And even less time to accept an answer (gray tick under the arrow, that'll become green if you click it! ;) )

Comment: @Eric : Thx! ;)